# regxp_replace and listagg influencing the performance of a query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, listagg

I want to improve the performance of a query. The query perfomance may be degraded because of the usage of listagg and regxp_like. Is there any other better option in place of these two FUNCTIONS which might improve the performance.

1. I'm not allowed to introduce any indexes to the tables I'm
   using.(There are more indexes added for all the tables... can not
   add any more)
2. Need to tweak around the query approach to improve its performance

**Query: Version 2 (Performance 64.796)**

```
    WITH SUAS_INFO AS
--Get SUAS service details
(SELECT S.NAME SUAS_SERVICE,
       S.SERVICEID SUAS_SERVICE_ID,
       SUB.NAME SUBSCRIBER_NAME,
       SMAUC.SERVICEID SMAUC_SERVICE_ID,
       SMAUC.NAME SMAUC_SERVICE,
       regexp_replace(LISTAGG(SIPVPN_MAIN.NAME, ',') WITHIN
                      GROUP(ORDER BY SIPVPN_MAIN.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3') SIPVPN_MAIN_SERVICE,
       regexp_replace(LISTAGG(SIPVPN_RED.NAME, ',') WITHIN
                      GROUP(ORDER BY SIPVPN_RED.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3') SIPVPN_RED_SERVICE,
       regexp_replace(LISTAGG(SIPSBV.NAME, ',') WITHIN
                      GROUP(ORDER BY SIPSBV.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3') SIPSBV_MAIN,
       regexp_replace(LISTAGG(SIPSBV_RED.NAME, ',') WITHIN
                      GROUP(ORDER BY SIPSBV_RED.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3') SIPSBV_RED,
       regexp_replace(LISTAGG(PORT_NO.NAME, ',') WITHIN
                      GROUP(ORDER BY PORT_NO.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3') SBC_PORT_NO
  FROM SERVICE S
  JOIN SUBSCRIBER SUB ON SUB.SUBSCRIBERID = S.SERVICE2SUBSCRIBER
                     AND S.SERVICE2SERVICETYPE = 1955100016
--Fetching SMAUC service
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO1 ON SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100029
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SMAUC ON SMAUC.SERVICEID = SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching SIPVPN MAIN service
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO2 ON SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100023
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPVPN_MAIN ON SIPVPN_MAIN.SERVICEID = SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching SIPVPN Redundant service
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO3 ON SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100042
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPVPN_RED ON SIPVPN_RED.SERVICEID = SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching SBV SIP Trunk IMS service
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO4 ON SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100030
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPSBV ON SIPSBV.SERVICEID = SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Redundant SBV SIP Trunk IMS service
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO5 ON SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100031
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPSBV_RED ON SIPSBV_RED.SERVICEID = SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
-- Fetching SBC Port details
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO6 ON SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SIPSBV.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 3100000065
                                   AND SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2DIMOBJECT = 3

  LEFT OUTER JOIN CIRCUIT CKT ON CKT.CIRCUITID = SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

  LEFT OUTER JOIN NODE PBX ON PBX.NODE2NODEDEF = 3100000000
                          AND PBX.NODEID IN
                              (CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTNODE, CKT.CIRCUIT2ENDNODE)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PORT P ON P.PORTID =
                            DECODE(PBX.NODEID,
                                   CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTNODE,
                                   CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTPORT,
                                   CKT.CIRCUIT2ENDPORT)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN NUMBEROBJECT NOB ON NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2OBJECT = P.PORTID
                                  AND NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2RELATION = 3100000031
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER PORT_NO ON PORT_NO.DIMNUMBERID = NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2NUMBER

 GROUP BY S.NAME, S.SERVICEID, SUB.NAME, SMAUC.SERVICEID, SMAUC.NAME

),

SMAUC_REL AS
(SELECT SMAUC1.SERVICEID SMAUC_SERVICEID,
       regexp_replace(LISTAGG(SID_MAIN.NAME, ',') WITHIN
                      GROUP(ORDER BY SID_MAIN.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3') SID_MAIN_NAME,
       regexp_replace(LISTAGG(SID_RED.NAME, ',') WITHIN
                      GROUP(ORDER BY SID_RED.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3') SID_RED_NAME,
       SEC_SUBNET.NAME SEC_SUBNET,
       GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET,
       GLBL_DMZ_IP.NAME GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP,
       CUST_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME CUST_DMZ_SUBNET,
       CUST_PUB_IP.NAME CUST_PUB_IP_EDGE,
       CUST_PUB_SBC.NAME CUST_PUB_SBC_B2B_IP,
       PUB_REV_PRX.NAME PUBLIC_REVRS_PRXY_MOB_IP,
       CUST_ACC_SUB.NAME CUST_ACC_SUBNET,
       EXT_SMAUC.REVERSEPROXYURL CUST_REVERSEPROXYURL,
       CUST_ACS_VLAN.VALUETO CUST_ACCZONE_VLAN,
       SEC_ZONE_VLAN.VALUETO SEC_ZONE_VLAN,
       GLBL_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO GLBL_DMZ_VLAN,
       CUST_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO CUST_DMZ_VLAN,
       MAIN_SBC.NAME MAIN_SBC_DEVICE
  FROM SERVICE SMAUC1
--Fetching SID Main service
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO6 ON SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100039
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SID_MAIN ON SID_MAIN.SERVICEID = SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching SID Redundant service
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO7 ON SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100038
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SID_RED ON SID_RED.SERVICEID = SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Secure Zone Subnet Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO8 ON SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100041
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER SEC_SUBNET ON SEC_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID = SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Global DMZ Zone Subnet Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO9 ON SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                   AND SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100036
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET ON GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID = SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer DMZ Subnet Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO10 ON SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100028
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_DMZ_SUBNET ON CUST_DMZ_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID = SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Global DMZ Zone IP Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO_11 ON SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                     AND SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100043
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_IP ON GLBL_DMZ_IP.DIMNUMBERID = SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Public Edge IP Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO11 ON SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100024
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_PUB_IP ON CUST_PUB_IP.DIMNUMBERID = SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Public SBC B2B IP Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO12 ON SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100026
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_PUB_SBC ON CUST_PUB_SBC.DIMNUMBERID = SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Public Reverse Proxy Mobile Access IP Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO13 ON SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100033
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER PUB_REV_PRX ON PUB_REV_PRX.DIMNUMBERID = SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Access Subnet Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO14 ON SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100035
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_ACC_SUB ON CUST_ACC_SUB.DIMNUMBERID = SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Access Zone VLAN
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO15 ON SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100034
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_ACS_VLAN ON CUST_ACS_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID = SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Secured Zone VLAN
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO16 ON SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100040
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER SEC_ZONE_VLAN ON SEC_ZONE_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID = SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Global DMZ VLAN
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO17 ON SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100032
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_VLAN ON GLBL_DMZ_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID = SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer DMZ VLAN
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO18 ON SO18.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO18.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100027
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_DMZ_VLAN ON CUST_DMZ_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID = SO18.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Main SBC Node
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO19 ON SO19.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                                    AND SO19.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100044
  LEFT OUTER JOIN NODE MAIN_SBC ON MAIN_SBC.NODEID = SO19.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching REVERSEPROXYURL for SMAUC port
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE_EXT_SMAUC EXT_SMAUC ON EXT_SMAUC.SERVICEID = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
 GROUP BY SMAUC1.SERVICEID,
          SEC_SUBNET.NAME,
          GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME,
          GLBL_DMZ_IP.NAME,
          CUST_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME,
          CUST_PUB_IP.NAME,
          CUST_PUB_SBC.NAME,
          PUB_REV_PRX.NAME,
          CUST_ACC_SUB.NAME,
          EXT_SMAUC.REVERSEPROXYURL,
          CUST_ACS_VLAN.VALUETO,
          SEC_ZONE_VLAN.VALUETO,
          GLBL_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO,
          CUST_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO,
          MAIN_SBC.NAME             
)
SELECT SUAS_INFO.SUAS_SERVICE,
       SUAS_INFO.SUBSCRIBER_NAME,
       SUAS_INFO.SMAUC_SERVICE,
       SUAS_INFO.SIPVPN_MAIN_SERVICE,
       SUAS_INFO.SIPVPN_RED_SERVICE,
       SMAUC_REL.SID_MAIN_NAME,
       SMAUC_REL.SID_RED_NAME,
       SUAS_INFO.SIPSBV_MAIN,
       SUAS_INFO.SIPSBV_RED,
       SMAUC_REL.CUST_ACCZONE_VLAN,
       SMAUC_REL.CUST_ACC_SUBNET,
       SMAUC_REL.SEC_ZONE_VLAN,
       SMAUC_REL.SEC_SUBNET,
       SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_VLAN,
       SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET,
       SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP,
       SMAUC_REL.CUST_DMZ_VLAN,
       SMAUC_REL.CUST_DMZ_SUBNET,
       SMAUC_REL.CUST_PUB_IP_EDGE,
       SMAUC_REL.CUST_PUB_SBC_B2B_IP,
       SMAUC_REL.PUBLIC_REVRS_PRXY_MOB_IP,
       SMAUC_REL.CUST_REVERSEPROXYURL,
       SUAS_INFO.SBC_PORT_NO,
       SMAUC_REL.MAIN_SBC_DEVICE
  FROM SUAS_INFO
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SMAUC_REL ON SMAUC_REL.SMAUC_SERVICEID = SUAS_INFO.SMAUC_SERVICE_ID
 ORDER BY SUAS_INFO.SUAS_SERVICE
```

**Query: Version 1 (Performance 10.327)**

```
WITH SUAS_INFO AS
--Get SUAS service details
(SELECT S.NAME SUAS_SERVICE,S.SERVICEID SUAS_SERVICE_ID,SUB.NAME SUBSCRIBER_NAME,SMAUC.SERVICEID SMAUC_SERVICE_ID,SMAUC.NAME SMAUC_SERVICE,SIPVPN_MAIN.NAME SIPVPN_MAIN_SERVICE,SIPVPN_RED.NAME SIPVPN_RED_SERVICE,SIPSBV.NAME SIPSBV_MAIN,SIPSBV_RED.NAME SIPSBV_RED
FROM SERVICE S 
JOIN SUBSCRIBER SUB
ON SUB.SUBSCRIBERID=S.SERVICE2SUBSCRIBER
AND S.SERVICE2SERVICETYPE=1955100016
--Fetching SMAUC service
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO1 ON SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=S.SERVICEID
AND SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100029
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SMAUC ON SMAUC.SERVICEID=SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching SIPVPN MAIN service
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO2 ON SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=S.SERVICEID
AND SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100023
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPVPN_MAIN ON SIPVPN_MAIN.SERVICEID=SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT


--Fetching SIPVPN Redundant service
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO3 ON SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=S.SERVICEID
AND SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100042
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPVPN_RED ON SIPVPN_RED.SERVICEID=SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT


--Fetching SBV SIP Trunk IMS service
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO4 ON SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=S.SERVICEID
AND SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100030
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPSBV ON SIPSBV.SERVICEID=SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT



--Fetching Redundant SBV SIP Trunk IMS service
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO5 ON SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=S.SERVICEID
AND SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100031
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPSBV_RED ON SIPSBV_RED.SERVICEID=SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT


),

SMAUC_REL AS
(SELECT SMAUC1.SERVICEID SMAUC_SERVICEID,SID_MAIN.NAME SID_MAIN_NAME,SID_RED.NAME SID_RED_NAME,SEC_SUBNET.NAME SEC_SUBNET,GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET,GLBL_DMZ_IP.NAME GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP,
CUST_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME CUST_DMZ_SUBNET,CUST_PUB_IP.NAME CUST_PUB_IP_EDGE,CUST_PUB_SBC.NAME CUST_PUB_SBC_B2B_IP,PUB_REV_PRX.NAME PUBLIC_REVRS_PRXY_MOB_IP,CUST_ACC_SUB.NAME CUST_ACC_SUBNET,EXT_SMAUC.REVERSEPROXYURL CUST_REVERSEPROXYURL,
CUST_ACS_VLAN.VALUETO CUST_ACCZONE_VLAN,SEC_ZONE_VLAN.VALUETO SEC_ZONE_VLAN,GLBL_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO GLBL_DMZ_VLAN,CUST_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO CUST_DMZ_VLAN
FROM SERVICE SMAUC1
--Fetching SID Main service
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO6 ON SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100039
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SID_MAIN ON SID_MAIN.SERVICEID=SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT


--Fetching SID Redundant service
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO7 ON SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100038
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SID_RED ON SID_RED.SERVICEID=SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT


--Fetching Secure Zone Subnet Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO8 ON SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100041
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER SEC_SUBNET ON SEC_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID=SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT


--Fetching Global DMZ Zone Subnet Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO9 ON SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100036
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET ON GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID=SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT


--Fetching Customer DMZ Subnet Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO10 ON SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100028
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_DMZ_SUBNET ON CUST_DMZ_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID=SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Global DMZ Zone IP Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO_11 ON SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100043
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_IP ON GLBL_DMZ_IP.DIMNUMBERID=SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Public Edge IP Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO11 ON SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100024
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_PUB_IP ON CUST_PUB_IP.DIMNUMBERID=SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Public SBC B2B IP Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO12 ON SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100026
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_PUB_SBC ON CUST_PUB_SBC.DIMNUMBERID=SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Public Reverse Proxy Mobile Access IP Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO13 ON SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100033
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER PUB_REV_PRX ON PUB_REV_PRX.DIMNUMBERID=SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Access Subnet Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO14 ON SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100035
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_ACC_SUB ON CUST_ACC_SUB.DIMNUMBERID=SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Access Zone VLAN
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO15 ON SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100034
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_ACS_VLAN ON CUST_ACS_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID=SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer Secured Zone VLAN
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO16 ON SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100040
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER SEC_ZONE_VLAN ON SEC_ZONE_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID=SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Global DMZ VLAN
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO17 ON SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100032
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_VLAN ON GLBL_DMZ_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID=SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT

--Fetching Customer DMZ VLAN
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO17 ON SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
AND SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=1955100027
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_DMZ_VLAN ON CUST_DMZ_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID=SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT


--Fetching REVERSEPROXYURL for SMAUC port
LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE_EXT_SMAUC EXT_SMAUC ON EXT_SMAUC.SERVICEID=SMAUC1.SERVICEID
)
,
SBC_PORT AS(SELECT MAIN_TRUNK.NAME SBV_SERVICE,PORT_NO.NAME SBC_PORT_NO
FROM SERVICE MAIN_TRUNK LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO
ON SO.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE=MAIN_TRUNK.SERVICEID
AND SO.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION=3100000065
AND SO.SERVICEOBJECT2DIMOBJECT=3
JOIN CIRCUIT CKT ON CKT.CIRCUITID=SO.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
LEFT OUTER JOIN NODE PBX ON PBX.NODE2NODEDEF=3100000000
AND PBX.NODEID IN (CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTNODE,CKT.CIRCUIT2ENDNODE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN PORT P ON P.PORTID=DECODE(PBX.NODEID,CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTNODE,CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTPORT,CKT.CIRCUIT2ENDPORT)
LEFT OUTER JOIN NUMBEROBJECT NOB ON NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2OBJECT=P.PORTID
AND NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2RELATION=3100000031
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER PORT_NO ON PORT_NO.DIMNUMBERID=NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2NUMBER)



SELECT SUAS_INFO.SUAS_SERVICE,SUAS_INFO.SUBSCRIBER_NAME,SUAS_INFO.SMAUC_SERVICE,SUAS_INFO.SIPVPN_MAIN_SERVICE,
SUAS_INFO.SIPVPN_RED_SERVICE,SUAS_INFO.SIPSBV_MAIN,SUAS_INFO.SIPSBV_RED,SMAUC_REL.SID_MAIN_NAME,SMAUC_REL.SID_RED_NAME,SMAUC_REL.CUST_ACC_SUBNET,
SMAUC_REL.SEC_SUBNET,SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET,SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP,SMAUC_REL.CUST_DMZ_SUBNET,SMAUC_REL.CUST_PUB_IP_EDGE,SMAUC_REL.CUST_PUB_SBC_B2B_IP,
SMAUC_REL.PUBLIC_REVRS_PRXY_MOB_IP,SMAUC_REL.CUST_ACCZONE_VLAN,SMAUC_REL.SEC_ZONE_VLAN,SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_VLAN,SMAUC_REL.CUST_DMZ_VLAN,SMAUC_REL.CUST_REVERSEPROXYURL,
SBC.SBC_PORT_NO SBC_PORT_NUM

FROM SUAS_INFO 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN SMAUC_REL ON SMAUC_REL.SMAUC_SERVICEID=SUAS_INFO.SMAUC_SERVICE_ID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN SBC_PORT SBC  ON SBC.SBV_SERVICE=SUAS_INFO.SIPSBV_MAIN
               ORDER BY SUAS_INFO.SUAS_SERVICE;
```

​

Comment: Do you really need all of the nested regexp_replace functions with the grouping and ordering? Otherwise it just looks like you've got a bunch of left joins on ID/int values which probably can't be tweaked too much.

Comment: The regexp_replace is used to fetch the distinct records from the list aggregator.... It is a must requirement.

Comment: This is a long and horrible query. Without an understanding of the business rules it implements and the data it works on there's not much we can do to advise you. You need to **edit your question** and provide a lot more information if you hope for a helpful answer.

Comment: run an explain plan, and review.

Comment: @Lohith I don't think that the regexp_replace functions  applied on a field of the select list has any influence on the performance of the query. At least you should start with this hypothesis and remove them (only the regexp_replace function, not the value it is appllied on). You can actually check the influence of the regexp by comparing the execution plan of the query with and without regexp. Also you should try to format the query, there is no indentation, there are line breaks in = expression before the =. Try to format the query that displays the syntactic structure of the query.

Comment: The query was performing better in its previous version. The previous version of query was giving the multiple records as a result of Cartesian product. This version of the query is improvised to collect the data using listagg to consolidate multiple records into single row. The regex_replace is additionally used to filter the duplicates within the aggregated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the small hint given by @Used-By-Already, I could do some tweaking in my query and it did solve my issue.
There was an important filter went unnoticed in my query.

```
/* Formatted on 11.20.2018 5:10:07  (QP5 v5.300) */
WITH SUAS_INFO
     AS --Get SUAS service details
        (  SELECT S.NAME        SUAS_SERVICE,
                  S.SERVICEID   SUAS_SERVICE_ID,
                  SUB.NAME      SUBSCRIBER_NAME,
                  SMAUC.SERVICEID SMAUC_SERVICE_ID,
                  SMAUC.NAME    SMAUC_SERVICE,
                  REGEXP_REPLACE (
                      LISTAGG (SIPVPN_MAIN.NAME, ',')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIPVPN_MAIN.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3')
                      SIPVPN_MAIN_SERVICE,
                  REGEXP_REPLACE (
                      LISTAGG (SIPVPN_RED.NAME, ',')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIPVPN_RED.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3')
                      SIPVPN_RED_SERVICE,
                  REGEXP_REPLACE (
                      LISTAGG (SIPSBV.NAME, ',')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIPSBV.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3')
                      SIPSBV_MAIN,
                  REGEXP_REPLACE (
                      LISTAGG (SIPSBV_RED.NAME, ',')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIPSBV_RED.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3')
                      SIPSBV_RED,
                  REGEXP_REPLACE (
                      LISTAGG (PORT_NO.NAME, ',')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PORT_NO.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3')
                      SBC_PORT_NO
             FROM SERVICE S
                  JOIN SUBSCRIBER SUB
                      ON SUB.SUBSCRIBERID = S.SERVICE2SUBSCRIBER
                  --Fetching SMAUC service
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO1
                      ON     SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                         AND SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100029
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SMAUC
                      ON SMAUC.SERVICEID = SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching SIPVPN MAIN service
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO2
                      ON     SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                         AND SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100023
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPVPN_MAIN
                      ON SIPVPN_MAIN.SERVICEID = SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching SIPVPN Redundant service
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO3
                      ON     SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                         AND SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100042
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPVPN_RED
                      ON SIPVPN_RED.SERVICEID = SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching SBV SIP Trunk IMS service
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO4
                      ON     SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                         AND SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100030
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPSBV
                      ON SIPSBV.SERVICEID = SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Redundant SBV SIP Trunk IMS service
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO5
                      ON     SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
                         AND SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100031
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SIPSBV_RED
                      ON SIPSBV_RED.SERVICEID = SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  -- Fetching SBC Port details
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO6
                      ON     SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SIPSBV.SERVICEID
                         AND SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 3100000065
                         AND SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2DIMOBJECT = 3
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN CIRCUIT CKT
                      ON CKT.CIRCUITID = SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN NODE PBX
                      ON     PBX.NODE2NODEDEF = 3100000000
                         AND PBX.NODEID IN
                                 (CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTNODE, CKT.CIRCUIT2ENDNODE)
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN PORT P
                      ON P.PORTID =
                             DECODE (
                                 PBX.NODEID,
                                 CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTNODE, CKT.CIRCUIT2STARTPORT,
                                 CKT.CIRCUIT2ENDPORT)
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN NUMBEROBJECT NOB
                      ON     NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2OBJECT = P.PORTID
                         AND NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2RELATION = 3100000031
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER PORT_NO
                      ON PORT_NO.DIMNUMBERID = NOB.NUMBEROBJECT2NUMBER
            WHERE S.SERVICE2SERVICETYPE = 1955100016
         GROUP BY S.NAME,
                  S.SERVICEID,
                  SUB.NAME,
                  SMAUC.SERVICEID,
                  SMAUC.NAME),
     SMAUC_REL
     AS (  SELECT SMAUC1.SERVICEID        SMAUC_SERVICEID,
                  REGEXP_REPLACE (
                      LISTAGG (SID_MAIN.NAME, ',')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SID_MAIN.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3')
                      SID_MAIN_NAME,
                  REGEXP_REPLACE (
                      LISTAGG (SID_RED.NAME, ',')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SID_RED.NAME),
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)',
                      '\1\3')
                      SID_RED_NAME,
                  SEC_SUBNET.NAME         SEC_SUBNET,
                  GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME    GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET,
                  GLBL_DMZ_IP.NAME        GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP,
                  CUST_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME    CUST_DMZ_SUBNET,
                  CUST_PUB_IP.NAME        CUST_PUB_IP_EDGE,
                  CUST_PUB_SBC.NAME       CUST_PUB_SBC_B2B_IP,
                  PUB_REV_PRX.NAME        PUBLIC_REVRS_PRXY_MOB_IP,
                  CUST_ACC_SUB.NAME       CUST_ACC_SUBNET,
                  EXT_SMAUC.REVERSEPROXYURL CUST_REVERSEPROXYURL,
                  CUST_ACS_VLAN.VALUETO   CUST_ACCZONE_VLAN,
                  SEC_ZONE_VLAN.VALUETO   SEC_ZONE_VLAN,
                  GLBL_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO   GLBL_DMZ_VLAN,
                  CUST_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO   CUST_DMZ_VLAN,
                  MAIN_SBC.NAME           MAIN_SBC_DEVICE
             FROM SERVICE SMAUC1
                  --Fetching SID Main service
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO6
                      ON     SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100039
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SID_MAIN
                      ON SID_MAIN.SERVICEID = SO6.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching SID Redundant service
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO7
                      ON     SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100038
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE SID_RED
                      ON SID_RED.SERVICEID = SO7.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Secure Zone Subnet Number
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO8
                      ON     SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100041
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER SEC_SUBNET
                      ON SEC_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID = SO8.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Global DMZ Zone Subnet Number
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO9
                      ON     SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100036
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET
                      ON GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID = SO9.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Customer DMZ Subnet Number
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO10
                      ON     SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100028
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_DMZ_SUBNET
                      ON CUST_DMZ_SUBNET.DIMNUMBERID =
                             SO10.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Global DMZ Zone IP Number
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO_11
                      ON     SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100043
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_IP
                      ON GLBL_DMZ_IP.DIMNUMBERID = SO_11.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Customer Public Edge IP Number
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO11
                      ON     SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100024
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_PUB_IP
                      ON CUST_PUB_IP.DIMNUMBERID = SO11.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Customer Public SBC B2B IP Number
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO12
                      ON     SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100026
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_PUB_SBC
                      ON CUST_PUB_SBC.DIMNUMBERID = SO12.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Public Reverse Proxy Mobile Access IP Number
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO13
                      ON     SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100033
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER PUB_REV_PRX
                      ON PUB_REV_PRX.DIMNUMBERID = SO13.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Customer Access Subnet Number
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO14
                      ON     SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100035
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_ACC_SUB
                      ON CUST_ACC_SUB.DIMNUMBERID = SO14.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Customer Access Zone VLAN
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO15
                      ON     SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100034
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_ACS_VLAN
                      ON CUST_ACS_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID = SO15.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Customer Secured Zone VLAN
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO16
                      ON     SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100040
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER SEC_ZONE_VLAN
                      ON SEC_ZONE_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID = SO16.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Global DMZ VLAN
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO17
                      ON     SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100032
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER GLBL_DMZ_VLAN
                      ON GLBL_DMZ_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID = SO17.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Customer DMZ VLAN
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO18
                      ON     SO18.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO18.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100027
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN DIMNUMBER CUST_DMZ_VLAN
                      ON CUST_DMZ_VLAN.DIMNUMBERID = SO18.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching Main SBC Node
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO19
                      ON     SO19.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
                         AND SO19.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100044
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN NODE MAIN_SBC
                      ON MAIN_SBC.NODEID = SO19.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
                  --Fetching REVERSEPROXYURL for SMAUC port
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE_EXT_SMAUC EXT_SMAUC
                      ON EXT_SMAUC.SERVICEID = SMAUC1.SERVICEID
            WHERE SMAUC1.SERVICE2SERVICETYPE = 1955100017
         GROUP BY SMAUC1.SERVICEID,
                  SEC_SUBNET.NAME,
                  GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME,
                  GLBL_DMZ_IP.NAME,
                  CUST_DMZ_SUBNET.NAME,
                  CUST_PUB_IP.NAME,
                  CUST_PUB_SBC.NAME,
                  PUB_REV_PRX.NAME,
                  CUST_ACC_SUB.NAME,
                  EXT_SMAUC.REVERSEPROXYURL,
                  CUST_ACS_VLAN.VALUETO,
                  SEC_ZONE_VLAN.VALUETO,
                  GLBL_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO,
                  CUST_DMZ_VLAN.VALUETO,
                  MAIN_SBC.NAME)
  SELECT SUAS_INFO.SUAS_SERVICE,
         SUAS_INFO.SUBSCRIBER_NAME,
         SUAS_INFO.SMAUC_SERVICE,
         SUAS_INFO.SIPVPN_MAIN_SERVICE,
         SUAS_INFO.SIPVPN_RED_SERVICE,
         SMAUC_REL.SID_MAIN_NAME,
         SMAUC_REL.SID_RED_NAME,
         SUAS_INFO.SIPSBV_MAIN,
         SUAS_INFO.SIPSBV_RED,
         SMAUC_REL.CUST_ACCZONE_VLAN,
         SMAUC_REL.CUST_ACC_SUBNET,
         SMAUC_REL.SEC_ZONE_VLAN,
         SMAUC_REL.SEC_SUBNET,
         SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_VLAN,
         SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_SUBNET,
         SMAUC_REL.GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP GLBL_DMZ_ZONE_IP,
         SMAUC_REL.CUST_DMZ_VLAN,
         SMAUC_REL.CUST_DMZ_SUBNET,
         SMAUC_REL.CUST_PUB_IP_EDGE,
         SMAUC_REL.CUST_PUB_SBC_B2B_IP,
         SMAUC_REL.PUBLIC_REVRS_PRXY_MOB_IP,
         SMAUC_REL.CUST_REVERSEPROXYURL,
         SUAS_INFO.SBC_PORT_NO,
         SMAUC_REL.MAIN_SBC_DEVICE
    FROM SUAS_INFO
         LEFT OUTER JOIN SMAUC_REL
             ON SMAUC_REL.SMAUC_SERVICEID = SUAS_INFO.SMAUC_SERVICE_ID
ORDER BY SUAS_INFO.SUAS_SERVICE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it through the SQL Tuning Advisor (if licensed).

Also, in cases where the outer join is just a look-up, you can eliminate an outer join by using a select statement in the select list (which sometimes provides for performance improvements).

Answer (score 0):

When confronted with a multi-part query such as yours, I would study each part independently - and make use of explain plans as I go.

For example, in your original query, the first CTE contains this:

```
 SELECT
    S.NAME SUAS_SERVICE
  , S.SERVICEID SUAS_SERVICE_ID
  , SUB.NAME SUBSCRIBER_NAME
  , SMAUC.SERVICEID SMAUC_SERVICE_ID
  , SMAUC.NAME SMAUC_SERVICE
  , SIPVPN_MAIN.NAME SIPVPN_MAIN_SERVICE
  , SIPVPN_RED.NAME SIPVPN_RED_SERVICE
  , SIPSBV.NAME SIPSBV_MAIN
  , SIPSBV_RED.NAME SIPSBV_RED
 FROM SERVICE S
 INNER JOIN SUBSCRIBER SUB ON SUB.SUBSCRIBERID = S.SERVICE2SUBSCRIBER AND S.SERVICE2SERVICETYPE = 1955100016
 --Fetching SMAUC service
 LEFT JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO1 ON SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID AND SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100029
 LEFT JOIN SERVICE SMAUC ON SMAUC.SERVICEID = SO1.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
 --Fetching SIPVPN MAIN service
 LEFT JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO2 ON SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID AND SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100023
 LEFT JOIN SERVICE SIPVPN_MAIN ON SIPVPN_MAIN.SERVICEID = SO2.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
 --Fetching SIPVPN Redundant service
 LEFT JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO3 ON SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID AND SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100042
 LEFT JOIN SERVICE SIPVPN_RED ON SIPVPN_RED.SERVICEID = SO3.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
 --Fetching SBV SIP Trunk IMS service
 LEFT JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO4 ON SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID AND SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100030
 LEFT JOIN SERVICE SIPSBV ON SIPSBV.SERVICEID = SO4.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
 --Fetching Redundant SBV SIP Trunk IMS service
 LEFT JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO5 ON SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID AND SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100031
 LEFT JOIN SERVICE SIPSBV_RED ON SIPSBV_RED.SERVICEID = SO5.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
```

Perhaps reducing the number of left joins will help?

```
SELECT
      S1.NAME SUAS_SERVICE
    , S1.SERVICEID SUAS_SERVICE_ID
    , SUB.NAME SUBSCRIBER_NAME
    , listagg(case when SO.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100029 then s2.SERVICEID end, ',') SMAUC_SERVICE_ID
    , listagg(case when SO.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100029 then s2.NAME end, ',') SMAUC_SERVICE
    , listagg(case when SO.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100023 then s2.NAME end, ',') SIPVPN_MAIN_SERVICE
    , listagg(case when SO.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100042 then s2.NAME end, ',') SIPVPN_RED_SERVICE
    , listagg(case when SO.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100030 then s2.NAME end, ',') SIPSBV_MAIN
    , listagg(case when SO.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION = 1955100031 then s2.NAME end, ',') SIPSBV_RED
FROM SERVICE S1 
INNER JOIN SUBSCRIBER SUB ON SUB.SUBSCRIBERID = S1.SERVICE2SUBSCRIBER 
LEFT JOIN SERVICEOBJECT SO ON SO.SERVICEOBJECT2SERVICE = S.SERVICEID
   AND SO.SERVICEOBJECT2RELATION IN (1955100029 , 1955100029, 1955100023, 1955100042, 1955100030, 1955100031)
LEFT JOIN SERVICE S2 ON SMAUC.SERVICEID = SO.SERVICEOBJECT2OBJECT
WHERE S1.SERVICE2SERVICETYPE = 1955100016
GROUP BY
      S1.NAME 
    , S1.SERVICEID 
    , SUB.NAME
```

Add the regexp_relace as needed.

Continue to the next CTE.

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion above did allow me to point the mistake I've done in my second CTE - 'SMAUC_REL'
I've missed one more join which is **very very important** filter which some how went unnoticed.
{  WHERE SMAUC1.SERVICE2SERVICETYPE = 1955100017}

Now my query performs much better, it takes only 5.959 secs to return the results.
Thanks again every body :)